# Can't find debugger in IDA PRO menu

Tags: ida, debugging, idapro-sdk, ida-plugin

I was going to debug something but I see IDA 6.8 + hexrays doesn't show the debugger tab in the menu for some .exe files.

This is an example when I didn't load any .exe:
[image]

This is another example when I'm loading the .exe I want to debug:
[image]

How can I debug this .exe? Maybe with a plugin for .net assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDA does not support debugging .NET binaries or more specifically the [CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) bytecode. To debug managed code you can use WinDbg with the SOS debugging extension ([SOS.dll](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sos-dll-sos-debugging-extension)).

You can also use [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy) which in addition is able to use the decompiled code for debugging make the experience similar to debugging with source code.